# Use sliding window to find variance for seasonal time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, variance, seasonality, moving-window

I would like to estimate the variance of a time series. Say, if the time series has a period of 24, and I want to estimate the variance using

$$ \sigma_t^2 = \frac{1}{2k+1} \sum^k_{-k} (y_{t+24k} - \bar{y}_t)^2 $$

where $\bar{y}_t = \frac{1}{2k+1} \sum^k_{-k} y_{t+24k}$.

I found some posts suggest using `roll apply`, but it seems to only work when estimating variance using neighbourhood data, which does not take the period into account.

Does anyone which function to use in this case?

Comment: Even though the question is phrased in terms of asking for an R function, I believe there is a genuine statistical question here, so I would not close this thread. @Jeannie, be aware that questions focused on software are off topic here, so it is advisable to phrase them in general statistical terms. Also, could you elaborate on *it seems to only work when estimating variance using neighbourhood data, which does not take the period into account*?